# Where to find selected filepath of SaveFileDialog (C#, Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xlsx, savefiledialog

I'm trying to export my dataTable as an Excel file. I can do this from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973274), but I'd like the user to be able to input the location the file is saved to. It seems like the SaveFileDialog class would work well.

My issue stems from the fact that I can't figure out where to find the filepath that has been specified by the user after hitting "save". I need that filepath to input into the ExportToExcel(ExcelFilePath) when I actually do the export of my dataTable.

[SaveFileDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netcore-3.1)

Sorry if I'm unclear, this is my first time asking a question here.

Comment: SaveFileDialog derives from [FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog). See its properties (FileName, for example). Btw, you don't actually need to use Interop to save an Excel File. If you want to use Interop, then make sure the users of you program also have Excel installed.

Comment: Extract the path with Path.GetDirectoryName from the FileName property

Comment: @Jimi Thank you! I appreciate it!

Comment: See an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206805/7444103) (last piece of code). Note that some properties are there to clarify an *intention* rather than to determine a functionality. You'll have to read more to understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted, the `SaveFileDialog` class is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netcore-3.1).

If we look at the top of that page, it shows the inheritance hierarchy:

<sub>Inheritance → [Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netcore-3.1) → [MarshalByRefObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?view=netcore-3.1) → [Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component?view=netcore-3.1) → [CommonDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.commondialog?view=netcore-3.1) → [FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog?view=netcore-3.1) → SaveFileDialog</sub>

Now if we follow the link to the [FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog?view=netcore-3.1) class and go to `Properties`, we see:

**[FileDialog.FileName Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=netcore-3.1)**
<sub>**Property Value**

[String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-3.1)

The file name selected in the file dialog box. The default value is an empty string ("").</sub>

<sub>**Remarks**

The file name includes both the file path and the extension. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty string ("").</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Wow that was easy haha. I really appreciate it.