# How do I get this painting event to work?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drawing, chess

I'm trying to create a procedure that will draw all of the squares (and later pieces) for a chess board in a starting position, but I only want it to draw these images once so that I can update the images regularly (representing that a piece has moved or been taken). The reason why I'm not using the following code is because I cannot remove the images when a piece needs to be updated.

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

End Sub
```

I'm not really 100% sure how to do this but this is what I've got so far:

```
Private Sub SetUpBoard(e As PaintEventArgs)

For i = 0 To 7 'This is the math behind generating the board colours in the right positions.
    For j = 0 To 7
        Board(0, i, j).sSquarePosition = Chr(j + 1) & (i + 1)
        If (j + 97) Mod 2 = (i + 1) Mod 2 Then
            Board(0, i, j).oSquareImage = My.Resources.bSquare
        Else
            Board(0, i, j).oSquareImage = My.Resources.wSquare
        End If
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Board(0, i, j).oSquareImage, (i * 50) + 1, (j * 50) + 1) 'Loads the images in the correct positions.
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

I've probably done this completely wrong but I'd like to know now rather than later, if that's okay. Thanks.

Comment: Draw the board once, on an image. Keep the image as a clean board. Then draw the clean board and on top of it, draw the pieces. Call the paint logic in `Paint` event and to trigger it, call `Invalidate` method of the drawing surface (the form).

Comment: You can draw the board on an Bitmap, set it as the BackGroundImage of a Control (a PictureBox or, possibly, a Custom Control) anchored inside a Form (you can redraw the Bitmap, if the canvas supports resizing). It's something like this: [Lines drawn on a large Bitmap are not visible when the image is saved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206805/7444103) (second snippet, except you draw a square instead of lines). Then draw the pieces on the surface of the canvas: the background Image remains untouched (it's a different *layer*).