# Graphics - Drawing lines are not even. Rounding errors converting single to integer?

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, gdi+, gdi

See this link/picture.
https://proscan.org/graphics%20rounding%20errors.png

The lines are not uniform Some are thinner and some are wider. The pattern changes when changing the form width. Using NET Framework 4.8.

Code to replicate problem:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
     
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Color c;
        int offsetY;

        g.DrawString("Method 1 - Using ScaleTransform", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 15);
        g.DrawString("Method 2 - Using ScaleTransform and bitmap", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 100);
        g.DrawString("Method 3 - Proves it's not a ScaleTransform issue" + Environment.NewLine + "as not using ScaleTransform and doing the scaling manualy", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 185);

        g.ScaleTransform(System.Convert.ToSingle(this.Width / (double)150), 1);

        // Method 1 - Using ScaleTransform
        offsetY = 35;
        for (int row = 0; row <= 49; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <= 99; col++)
            {
                if (col % 2 == 0)
                    c = Color.SkyBlue;
                else
                    c = Color.Black;
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c), col + 10, row + offsetY, 1, 1);
            }
        }

        // Method 2 - Using ScaleTransform and bitmap
        offsetY = 120;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor; // Without this, lines appear even but are burry (lines blended together)
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 50))
        {
            using (Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                for (int row = 0; row <= 49; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col <= 99; col++)
                    {
                        if (col % 2 == 0)
                            c = Color.SkyBlue;
                        else
                            c = Color.Black;
                        g1.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c), col, row, 1, 1); // Same effect using SetPixel(col, row, c)
                    }
                }
            }
            g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(10, offsetY, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }


        // Method 3 - Proves it's not a ScaleTransform issue as not using ScaleTransform and doing the scaling manualy
        offsetY = 220;
        g.ResetTransform();
        for (int row = 0; row <= 49; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <= 99; col++)
            {
                if (col % 2 == 0)
                    c = Color.SkyBlue;
                else
                    c = Color.Black;
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c), System.Convert.ToSingle((col + 10) * (this.Width / (double)150)), System.Convert.ToSingle(row + offsetY), System.Convert.ToSingle(1 * (this.Width / (double)150)), System.Convert.ToSingle(1 * (this.Height / (double)150)));
            }
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

I tried various InterpolationMode modes, and putting the lines in a bitmap and drawing the bitmap.
I expected the lines width to be uniform

Comment: Last method: `g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(c), (col + 10) * (Width / 150), row + offsetY, Width / 150, Height / 150);`. Drawing straight lines (or rectangles) in parallel, remove any roundings that come from conversions. You have `int` to `double` (for unknown reasons) to `float`

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what you consider to be an error? I'm willing to bet that the actual error is in your expectations. Provide examples of actual data that produces the result you expect and data that doesn't produce the result you expect and what those results are. You need to have actually debugged the code, not just looked at the end result on screen. You're a developer, not a user, so you need to use the development tools at your disposal.

Comment: Now, I think about it more, it's impossible to get all the line widths the same. If the grid (or form width) is 150 px with 100 columns, that would equal to 1.5 px per line. It can be done if the grid width is in multiples of 100's.

Comment: Yes, you can. It depends on what you draw an how. What you cannot do is to introduce, as mentioned, variable errors that come from rounding. Note also that casting to `int` or performing integer divisions, it's not the same thing as using conversion methods - not even considering multiple conversions - as `Convert.ToSomething()`: you introduce variance in the error, while, if an error is inevitable, you want it constant, so you can compensate -- You **can** use `float` values, to fill a region; see [the methods in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206805/7444103), for example

Comment: I need to keep this g.ScaleTransform(Convert.ToSingle(this.Width / (double)150), 1) the way it is. If I remove the (double) then the grid width will jump (or not resize with the form width until the next whole number). I'm going to use the bitmap method and remove the InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor. At least all the lines are same amount of width, just slightly burry. Thank you all.

Comment: This: `Convert.ToSingle(this.Width / (double)150)` is this: `this.Width / 150f`, except, as mentioned already, casting an int to double, then to float, you introduce an error that is not constant, since it depends on rounding (not to mention the fact that you have multiple conversions in a tight nested loop). For example, `(int)100.6f` and `Convert.ToInt32(100.6f)` are not the same thing. But the former has *constant behavior*, which allows to generate evenly spaced straight lines

Comment: I should have used this example in the code to be less confusing: ScaleTransform(2.1, 1). If sx is a whole number then the lines are even width. If sx is a fraction then some lines are thinner and some are thicker. I was trying to expand a grid to the width of the form so if the form is 210 px wide, the grid should be 210 wide. Form width 200 works great and 210 is uneven. Anyways I put all the lines in a bitmap so the lines are even.